# Rails: create two nested items in controller but only one shows in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

**Consider the following:**

**customer.rb**

```
module Refinery
    class Customer < Refinery::Core::BaseModel      
      has_many :users, :class_name => "Refinery::User"

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
    end
  end
end
```

**user_decorator.rb**

```
Refinery::User.class_eval do
  belongs_to :customer, :class_name => 'Refinery::Customer'
end
```

**customer_controller.rb**

```
module Refinery
  class UsersController
    def new
      @customer = ::Refinery::Customer.new
      # tried using build here as well with no sucess
      @owner = @customer.users.new
      @inputer = @customer.users.new

      # raise @customer.users.length.to_yaml => returns 2 so that works!
    end
  end
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @customer do |f| %>
  <% if @customer.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@customer.errors.count, "error") %> need to be corrected before continuing:</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @customer.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <!-- company fields here -->
  <%= fields_for :users do |user| %>
    <div>
      <%= user.label :first_name %>
      <%= user.text_field :first_name %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= user.label :last_name %>
      <%= user.text_field :last_name %>
    </div>
    <!-- more user fields here etc -->
  <% end $>
<% end %>
```

When I view this page only one user shows up. The ids for the fields look like this also:

```
<div>
   <label for="users_last_name">Last name</label>
   <input id="users_last_name" name="users[last_name]" size="30" type="text">
</div>
```

I think there should be some kind of index in there right? (i.e. 0, 1, 2 etc for as if iterating over an array.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You miss the f.fields_for

Comment: @AnezioCampos hey that did it! Post this as a answer and I'll accept and upvote it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the

```
f.fields_for
```

Just add it and it should work